# Mapping a Disk under the complex exponential function (without using conformal mapping)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I´m stuck trying to find the image of the circle $|z|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ under the function $f(z)=e^z$. I know the transformation results in $w=f(z)=u+iv$, with $u = e^x\cos x$ and $v=e^x\sin x$, having both $x$ and $y$ restricted in the interval $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

But it has to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZHYH.png). I don´t know how to get a parametric solution for it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is a problem from Complex Analysis by Gamelin, and it appears in a section prior to the introduction of differentiation, so conformal mapping (wich I understand is an application of complex differentiation) is not an acceptable solution. It must be a way to obtain the same equation by using classical mapping methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuously differentiable (in particular, holomorphic) applications map boundaries into boundaries, hence it is enough to understand the image of $|z|=\frac{\pi}{2}$, made by points of the form $\frac{\pi}{2}e^{i\theta} = \frac{\pi}{2}\cos\theta + i\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\theta $ for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. By exponentiating this thing we get

$$ e^{\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\theta}\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\theta\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\theta\right)\right] $$
i.e. a regular curve contained in the annulus $e^{-\pi/2}\leq |z|\leq e^{\pi/2}$ and in the half-plane $\text{Re}(z)\geq 0$:

$\hspace1in$[image]

It is a sort of cardioid.

Comment: thanks for answering but I was kinda looking for a method to do this without using conformal mapping, since this very problem comes from a book in a section prior to the study of analytical function. But thank you very much for your time and help.